# Is it possible, in Ruby, to have DOM parsing for parts of a huge XML that is otherwise SAX-parsed?

Tags: ruby, xml, dom, sax

I need to parse a humongous XML file (70GB big) in Ruby and currently I'm using Nokogiri's SAX parser. This file is very big, but it's composed of one root element and then a lot of entries all of which are perfectly manageable in size. Having to do all the parsing in an event-based manner is needlesly hard. Is there a way to parse each of those entries as DOM even though the whole file is parsed as SAX?

For example, I'm thinking of building up the dom with all the `start_element` and `close_element` calls and in the last one, when the record is closed, take that DOM and do the processing there. Surelly I'm not the first one to think of such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

rminner wrote [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1172364)

"Personally i think XML::DOM is not going to be the right solution, if your input xml file is very large. My perfered choice for parsing xml is XML::Twig. I am using it to parse very large files, and it is doing it quickly with a low memory usage. The same may apply for other modules, however i am most familiar with XML::Twig.

"I whipped up a short example, on how you can do the parsing with XML::Twig. Since i do not know exactly what you intend to do, i added several example method calls to get you on the right track (in case you ever decide to use it)."

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
#use Data::Dumper::Concise; # i prefer Data::Dumper::Concise
use XML::Twig;

# individually process each <signal> element
sub signal_handler {
        my ($data, $twig, $elem) = @_;

        # get the attributes of $elem (<signal>)
        my $atts = $elem->atts();  

        if ($atts->{'sigid'} == 3464) {
                print "Found <signal> with sigid == 3464:\n",$elem->sp
+rint(),"\n";
                print "<PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE>";<STDIN>;
        }

        # if you want to access the element in a way similar to XML::S
+imple:
        my $xml_simple_style_elem = $elem->simplify();

        # check out the simplified structure:
        print Dumper($xml_simple_style_elem);
        print "<PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE>";<STDIN>;

        # Example for Data Collection:
        my ($sigid, $id) = @{$atts}{qw/sigid id/};
        if (defined $sigid and defined $id) {
                $data->{sigid_id_count}{$sigid}{$id}++;
        }

        # get all elements below <signal> which are called <foo>
        my @foo_subelements  = $elem->descendants('foo');

        $twig->purge; # explicitly free the memory
};

sub main {
        my $fn = shift @ARGV;
        my %collected_data;

        my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
                twig_roots => {
                        'signal'     =>  sub {signal_handler(\%collect
+ed_data, @_);},
                },
        );
        eval {
                $twig->parsefile($fn);
        };
        if ($@) {
                print STDERR "Failed to parse '$fn' ($@)\n";
        }
        if (%collected_data) {
                print "I collected the following data:\n",Dumper(\%col
+lected_data);
        }
}
main();
```

Please [click here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1172354) for Full Documentation

Comment: I know you provided an attribution of sorts, but unless you're rminner, you could make it clearer that you are quoting somebody else's opinion and code.

Comment: @Alohci, reference is mentioned in the post